# Graphing Trigonometric Functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

In my attempt to graph the transformation of a trigonometric function, I found myself having to work section by section. I researched the `\foreach` function to shorten the code and make it more robust and reusable, but it kept on giving me errors.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.append style = {   pin distance=1ex, 
                                                    inner sep=1pt,
                                                    pin edge={solid,-,shorten <=-3pt}
                                                }]
    \begin{axis}[
     axis lines=middle,clip=false,,axis on top,
            declare function={f(\x)=2*cos(4*\x+3*pi)+1;},
            xmin=-2.75,xmax=1,ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            ytick={-1,3},
            xtick={-3*pi/4,-5*pi/8, -pi/2, -3*pi/8, -pi/4,-pi/8,pi/8, pi/4},    
            xticklabels={   $-\frac{3\pi}{4}$, 
                            $-\frac{5\pi}{8}$, 
                            $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, 
                            $-\frac{3\pi}{8}$,
                            $-\frac{\pi}{4}$,
                            $-\frac{\pi}{8}$,
                            $\frac{\pi}{8}$,
                            $\frac{\pi}{4}$},
            xticklabel style={black},
            yticklabel style={black,fill=white,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            x post scale=2,
            trig format plots=rad]
        \addplot[domain=-3*pi/4:-pi/4,samples=200,black,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot[domain=-13*pi/16:-3*pi/4,samples=200,gray,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot[domain=-pi/4:5*pi/16,samples=200,gray,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot [draw=none,mark=*] coordinates {
            (-3*pi/4,{f(-3*pi/4)})
            (-5*pi/8,{f(-5*pi/8)})
            (-pi/2,{f(-pi/2)})
            (-3*pi/8,{f(-3*pi/8)})
            (-pi/4,{f(-pi/4)})
            (-pi/8,{f(-pi/8)})
            (0,{f(0)})
            (pi/8,{f(pi/8)})
            (pi/4,{f(pi/4)})
        };
        \addplot[dashed, domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=200,gray]{3}; % y = 3 max value
        \addplot[dashed, domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=200,gray]{-1}; % y = -1 min value
        \addplot[densely dotted, domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=200,gray]{1}; % vertical shift
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Function Label
        \node[pin={[pin distance = 4ex]-80:{\footnotesize $f(x)=2\cos(4x+3\pi)+1$}},scale=1] at (pi/16,-0.5) {};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Period Label
        \path (-3*pi/4,0) coordinate (P);           
        \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate, thick,color=black]%OrangeRed] 
            (-pi/4,-2) -- (P|--pi/4,-2) node[midway,below=0.5ex,font=\footnotesize,scale=1]{$\text{Period, }T=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Range Label
        \path (-13*pi/16-0.05,3) coordinate (R);
        \draw [decoration={brace,mirror}, decorate,thick,color=black]%OrangeRed] 
            (R) -- (R|-0,-1) node[midway,left=1ex,font=\footnotesize,text width=6em,scale=1]{Range:\\$-1\leq f(x)\leq 3$};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Amplitude Label
        \draw[densely dotted,gray] (-pi/4,3) --coordinate (A) (-pi/4,1) 
            node[midway,font=\footnotesize,scale=1,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,text=black]{$|A|=2$} ;
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Coordinate Labels
        \node[pin={90:{\footnotesize $\left(-\frac{3\pi}{4},3\right)$}},scale=0.75, above] at (-3*pi/4,3) {};
        \node[pin={45:{\footnotesize $\left(-\frac{5\pi}{8},1\right)$}},scale=0.75, above right] at (-5*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin={-90:{\footnotesize $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},-1\right)$}},scale=0.75, below] at (-pi/2,-1) {};
        \node[pin={-15:{\footnotesize $\left(-\frac{3\pi}{8},1\right)$}},scale=0.75,below right] at (-3*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin={90:{\footnotesize $\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},3\right)$}},scale=0.75, above] at (-pi/4,3) {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Is it possible to iterate a few of the steps above and improve the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The focus of this answer is on the question of loops vs. pgfplots. Loops in pgfplots can be slightly more tricky than in plain Ti*k*Z. This is because of the way `pgfplots` surveys and finally "does" the contents of the axis. A detailed discussion can be found in section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the manual v1.16. In short, a plain `\foreach` may not always work in its simplest implementation.

However, you can definitely use loops here to simplify things. This also largely avoids the need to define styles because if you repeat things in a loop you only need to change things once. The changes include:

A. The use of `samples at` in

```
\addplot [draw=none,mark=*,samples at={-3/4,-5/8,...,1/4}] 
    ({x*pi},{f(x*pi)});
```

instead of the long list of explicit coordinates,

B. A loop over three plots for the horizontal dashed plots (along with a reduction of the number of samples), i.e.

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,1,3}{% y = -1,1,3 max value
    \addplot[dashed, domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=2,gray]{#1};}
```

instead of three separate plots.

C. Just one plot

```
\addplot[domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=300,gray,thick]{f(\x)};
```

instead of three.

D. A pretty-print of the x tick labels from the inputs, which spares you from adding the long list of `xticklabels`.

Simplifying the pins to a loop does not make things much more elegant here because you have too many things specific to each of them (but I slightly changed the style, similar to Zarko's post which I see now). You could do it with the `\edef\temp{\noexpand...}\temp` trick from p. 543 of the manual.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.append style = {pin distance=1ex, 
                                                 inner sep=1pt,
                                                 font=\footnotesize,
                                                  pin edge={solid,-,shorten <=-3pt}
                                                }]

    \begin{axis}[
     axis lines=middle,clip=false,,axis on top,
            declare function={f(\x)=2*cos(4*\x+3*pi)+1;},
            xmin=-2.75,xmax=1,ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            ytick={-1,3},
            xtick={-3*pi/4,-5*pi/8, -pi/2, -3*pi/8, -pi/4,-pi/8,pi/8, pi/4},    
            xticklabel={%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynum}{round(abs(8*\tick/pi))}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mygcd}{gcd(8,\mynum)}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynum}{\mynum/\mygcd}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myden}{8/\mygcd}%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{2+sign(\tick)*ifthenelse(\mynum==1,2,1)}%
            $\ifcase\itest
               -\frac{\pi}{\myden}
              \or
               -\frac{\mynum\pi}{\myden}
              \or 
               0
              \or 
               \frac{\mynum\pi}{\myden}
              \or
               \frac{\pi}{\myden}
              \fi$%
                },
            xticklabel style={black},
            yticklabel style={black,fill=white,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            x post scale=2,
            trig format plots=rad]
        \addplot[domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=300,gray,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot [draw=none,mark=*,samples at={-3/4,-5/8,...,1/4}] 
        ({x*pi},{f(x*pi)});     
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,1,3}{% y = -1,1,3 max value
        \addplot[dashed, domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,samples=2,gray]{#1};} 
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Function Label
        \node[pin={[pin distance = 4ex]-80:{\footnotesize $f(x)=2\cos(4x+3\pi)+1$}},scale=1] at (pi/16,-0.5) {};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Period Label
        \path (-3*pi/4,0) coordinate (P);           
        \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate, thick,color=black]%OrangeRed] 
            (-pi/4,-2) -- (P|--pi/4,-2) node[midway,below=0.5ex,font=\footnotesize,scale=1]{$\text{Period, }T=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Range Label
        \path (-13*pi/16-0.05,3) coordinate (R);
        \draw [decoration={brace,mirror}, decorate,thick,color=black]%OrangeRed] 
            (R) -- (R|-0,-1) node[midway,left=1ex,font=\footnotesize,text width=6em,scale=1]{Range:\\$-1\leq f(x)\leq 3$};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Amplitude Label
        \draw[densely dotted,gray] (-pi/4,3) --coordinate (A) (-pi/4,1) 
            node[midway,font=\footnotesize,scale=1,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,text=black]{$|A|=2$} ;
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Coordinate Labels
        \node[pin={90:{$\left(-\frac{3\pi}{4},3\right)$}}] at (-3*pi/4,3) {};
        \node[pin={45:{$\left(-\frac{5\pi}{8},1\right)$}}] at (-5*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin={-90:{$\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},-1\right)$}}] at (-pi/2,-1) {};
        \node[pin={-15:{$\left(-\frac{3\pi}{8},1\right)$}}] at (-3*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin={90:{$\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},3\right)$}}] at (-pi/4,3) {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Your program is quite well written, so only minor improvements are possible. For example:

- collecting all style option in nodes' style definition
- defining common style for braces (you may liked fancy version defined in the `calligraphy` library)
- common option for plot move to `axes` options
- not repeating default settings. For example, `scale=1` is superfluous, etc

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be loaded after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
                      > = {Stealth[length=4pt]},
every pin/.append style = {pin distance=1.5ex,
                           inner sep=1pt, font=\footnotesize,
                           pin edge={solid, shorten <=-3pt}
                           },
            Brace/.style = {decorate,% fancy, for fun
                            decoration={calligraphic brace,
                            raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
                            thick, pen colour={red}
                            },
              lbl/.style = {fill=white,align=center,font=\footnotesize,
                           inner sep=1pt,}
                        ]
    \begin{axis}[
     axis lines=middle,clip=false,axis on top,
            declare function={f(\x)=2*cos(4*\x+3*pi)+1;},
            xmin=-2.75,xmax=1,ymin=-2,ymax=5,
            ytick={-1,3},
            xtick={-3*pi/4,-5*pi/8, -pi/2, -3*pi/8, -pi/4,-pi/8,pi/8, pi/4},
            xticklabels={   $-\frac{3\pi}{4}$,
                            $-\frac{5\pi}{8}$,
                            $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
                            $-\frac{3\pi}{8}$,
                            $-\frac{\pi}{4}$,
                            $-\frac{\pi}{8}$,
                            $\frac{\pi}{8}$,
                            $\frac{\pi}{4}$},
            yticklabel style={fill=white,inner sep=1pt},
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            x post scale=2,
            trig format plots=rad,
            samples=100,
                    ]
%
        \addplot[domain=-13*pi/16:5*pi/16,gray!50,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot[domain=-3*pi/4:-pi/4,black,thick]{f(\x)};
        \addplot[draw=none,mark=*] coordinates {
            (-3*pi/4,{f(-3*pi/4)})
            (-5*pi/8,{f(-5*pi/8)})
            (-pi/2,{f(-pi/2)})
            (-3*pi/8,{f(-3*pi/8)})
            (-pi/4,{f(-pi/4)})
            (-pi/8,{f(-pi/8)})
            (0,{f(0)})
            (pi/8,{f(pi/8)})
            (pi/4,{f(pi/4)})
        };
        \draw[dashed,gray] (-13*pi/16, 3) -- (5*pi/16, 3);% max value
        \draw[dotted,gray] (-13*pi/16, 1) -- (5*pi/16, 1);% DC value
        \draw[dashed,gray] (-13*pi/16,-1) -- (5*pi/16,-1);% min value
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Function Label
        \node[pin=-80:{$f(x)=2\cos(4x+3\pi)+1$}] at (pi/32,-0.803) {};
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Period Label
        \draw[Brace] (-pi/4,-1.9) -- node[below=2ex,lbl]{Period, $T=\pi/2$} (-3*pi/4,-1.9) ;
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Range Label
        \draw[Brace]%OrangeRed
            (-13*pi/16,-1) -- node[left=1em,lbl] {Range:\\$-1\leq f(x)\leq 3$} (-13*pi/16,3);
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Amplitude Label
        \draw[densely dotted,gray,<->] (-pi/4,3) --
                    node[sloped, lbl, text=black] {$|A|=2$} (-pi/4,1);
        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Coordinate Labels
        \node[pin= 90:{$\left(-\frac{3\pi}{4},3\right)$}] at (-3*pi/4,3) {};
        \node[pin= 45:{$\left(-\frac{5\pi}{8},1\right)$}] at (-5*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin=-90:{$\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},-1\right)$}] at (-pi/2,-1) {};
        \node[pin=-15:{$\left(-\frac{3\pi}{8},1\right)$}] at (-3*pi/8,1) {};
        \node[pin= 90:{$\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},3 \right)$}] at (-pi/4,3) {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]